# React: send ReactNode via context to an ancestor and render it there

Tags: reactjs, react-context, portal

Is trere a suggested way to render part of a children component in an ancestor (like the Portal but in component tree)?

I mean to send the node there by a `Context` or provide the `Ref` throught props or transport that by `callbacks` up? Is there a way to use real `Portal`?

I prefer functional components please.

```
const Children = () => <>
<Primary/>
<ToAncestor><Secondary/></ToAncestor>
<>

const Parent = () => <Children/>

const Ancestor = () => <>
<Parent/>
<SecondaryContentFromChildren/> <-- the magic
<>
```

Thank you ❤️